# bq load multiple files gives error Too many positional args

Tags: csv, command-line, google-bigquery

I have to load about 40 files into a table.

If I execute the command

```
bq load -F '|' my_ds.testable my_ds.testable.txt-3 testable.json
```

It works, and that one file is loaded

However, if I try to use a wildcard to load multiple files:

```
bq load -F '|' my_ds.testable my_ds.testable.txt-3* testable.json
```

I get the error message:

> Too many positional args, still have ['my_ds.testable.txt-31',
>   'my_ds.testable.txt-32', 'testable.json']

Any thoughts?

Comment: Is the issue that your terminal is expanding the `*` since you didn't escape it?